# Check in the_content if a string exists

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the situation.

I have setup a site using Magento-Wordpress integration. The integration works so I can call in the Magento site whatever I want from wordpress.

I want to show in the product page, a post from wordpress, that contains a specific word. 
In my opinion, I have to search in the_content() of the posts the title of the product and then bring the post_meta I need.

The problem is that I cannot get it working.
I tried this:

```
<?php $name_of_product = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
<?php echo $name_of_product ; ?>
<?php   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'avada_portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 103 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();           

    <?php  
        $pos = strpos( get_the_content(), "[Dominos]" );
        var_dump($pos);
        if ( ! (FALSE == $pos) ) {  
        the_content();  
        the_title(); 
        }
        else{echo ("NOTHING HERE");}
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;                                       
?>
```

but didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened, if it didn't work?

Comment: Also, try changing `===` to `==`. From the manual: `Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.`

Comment: use var_dump on the `get_the_content()` function and verify if contains the requested string.

Comment: It just goes to the else part of the if function. Whatever I insert it just wont bother.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump()` as was suggested. Also, you shouldn't be doing `echo the_title();`...it's just `the_title();`.

Comment: what you see in `var_dump($pos)`?

Comment: var_dump($pos) result is bool(false) NOTHING HERE.

Comment: So it mean in your content no find your text ("[13801580]")

Comment: You don't want to `var_dump($pos)`...you want to `var_dump(get_the_content())`...to see if it actually contains what you're looking for.

Comment: And use next `if( function_exists( 'get_the_content' )){var_dump(get_the_content());}`

Comment: We made something. I go this:
`string(204) "[mwi_product sku="13801580,13801584,13801584,13801578,13801580" title="true" title_tag="h2" desc="false" img="true" img_width="250" price="false" type="false" btn_color="blue" btn_link="button" cols="9"/]"`

Comment: This is the_content() I have written. It is a shortcode. What now if I want to search if a string is contained in there??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your `var_dump()` output, you should be able to simply use:

```
if ( strpos( get_the_content(), '13801580' ) !== false) {
    the_content();  
    the_title(); 
}
```

Comment: Very nice. This answer works. But to take it as correct is not final.
If I want to compare a string like:
`if ( strpos( get_the_content(),0 $product_title ) !== false) {
    the_content();  
    the_title(); 
}`
How would I do it?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You should mark this as resolved and ask a new one.

Comment: Lol. Is that so different thing to ask. I cannot get it working but I guess it is just a syntactical error. Please check my question and if you really believe it is a whole new question I will accept your answer.

Comment: If you look at your `var_dump()` output, there is no product title in that string. So yes, this is a completely different question.

Comment: Yes I was about to say the same. Anywayz, thanks a lot for your instant assistance!!!

Answer (score -1):

First check your `$content`, maybe it empty:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'avada_portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 103 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();           

        $content = get_the_content();

        if($content){
          echo 'content present';
        }else{
          echo 'no content!!!';
        }

    endwhile;
```

---

if not empty and that is shortcode you can use next code for example:

```
 $content = '[mwi_product sku="13801580,13801584,13801584,13801578,13801580" title="true" title_tag="h2" desc="false" img="true" img_width="250" price="false" type="false" btn_color="blue" btn_link="button" cols="9"/]';

    $need_find = array('13801580', '13801584');
    foreach($need_find as $find){
      if(strpos( $content,  $find) !== false) { 
          echo 'Find your text: '.$find.'</br>';
      }

    }
```